# Mac Terminal - moving files

Tags: terminal, macintosh

I am trying to use Mac Terminal command to move files to a new location.

I have a list of almost 2000 filenames with full paths in a text file. (All of them are in one parent directory, but distributed within multiple sub-directories.) I want to move these files into a single folder outside the parent directory.

How do I do this? I need the command to do something like this:

```
mv 'files listed in abc.txt' to destination
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get to the textfile? There may be easy solutions. Otherwise looping the file line by line would be my choice, but there may be better.

Comment: I used grep -lir 'keyword' /parentdirectory/* > abc.txt to get the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like create a tar file using your text file as an include file, then untar the file in the new location.

Or a one liner like this might work

```
while read -r i; do mv "$i" "/new/path/$i" ; done < abc.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the filenames in abc.txt follow the format /parentfolder/subfolder_x/filename.xml, where x ranges from 1 to 36. I am trying to move them from these many different locations into a single destination folder. With the above command, I get an error "No such file or directory." It appears that the command is trying to recreate the entire directory structure (/subfolder_x.filename.xml) in the destination folder. Is there a way I can ignore the source path in each filename while moving to the destination folder?

Comment: @Spartanblogger did you change "/new/path" to path you want the files to go to?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, I did.

Comment: It worked. Instead of "/new/path/$i" I used just "/new/path/" and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that doesn't require creating a temporary file first, and will work on all possible filenames:

```
for f in /parentdirectory/*; do
    if grep -q 'keyword' "$f"; then
        mv "$f" /someotherdir
    fi
done
```

Comment: How do I run this? In the terminal? Or in the AppleScript editor?

Comment: In a terminal. This code will work in any (mostly) POSIX-compliant shell (bash, dash, zsh, ksh, ...).

Comment: Tried it. It did not do anything.

Answer (score -1):

I tested this in debian for a list in which there was one file path per line

```
  cat list.txt | xargs mv -R -t copy_to_this_directory
```

Comment: I assume the files also didn't contain spaces. The `mv` on my Debian workstation from GNU coreutils doesn't have a `-R` option, and `-t` is a GNU extension that may not be available on Mac OS X